# Приложение Heroku не отображает символы кириллицы с кодировкой UTF-8 по умолчанию

Tags: python, utf-8, heroku, кодировка

Всем здравствуйте!
Я новичок в использовании облачных платформ, таких как Heroku. Я написала на python парсер для сайта и обернула его в telegram бота. Принцип работы бота следующий: пользователь отправляет ссылку и количество страниц, а бот возвращает таблицу с данными из объявлений.

- Но проблема заключается в том, что при запуске кода в PyCharm все работает, бот отправляет csv файл с информацией на кириллице, но когда бот был загружен на платформу Heroku и был запущен, то начал отправлять непонятные наборы символов, вроде как в кодировке Windows-1250.
- Для решения проблемы я в настройках heroku config vars поставила LANG = en_US.UTF-8. Не помогло. Записывала encoding = 'utf-8' в конструкциях with open() и csv.writer() - тоже никаких изменений.

Ошибка кроется в неверном понимании кодировки для кириллици и её правильном оформлении конкретно для heroku.

```
#функция заполняет таблицу информацией из массива массивов items
    def save_file(items):
      with open('cars_tab.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Марка', 'Ссылка', 'Цена в $', 'Цена в UAH', 'Город'])
        for item in items:
          writer.writerow([item['title'], item['link'], item['usd_price'], item['uah_price'], item['city']])
      return file
```

Скажите, в чем моя ошибка и как я могу сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял информацию на кириллице? Опишите, пожалуйста, максимально подробно и понятно. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В данном сообществе принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке. Потрудитесь перевести вопрос, иначе он будет закрыт. Так же настоятельно советую ознакомится со справкой

Comment: Для того, что бы дать ответ, нужно понимать, в какой кодировке вы получаете данные из источника и как храните. Можете привести код для анализа?

Comment: Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Comment: спасибо за наводки, сейчас попробую понять в какой кодировке полученные данные, и дополню свой вопрос.

Comment: А если передать `encoding="utf-8"` в `open()`?

Comment: Да, я пробовала передавать encoding = "utf-8" как в open(), так и в csv.writer(), и в том и в другом случае, в файле вместо кириллицы оказываются кракозябры.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такая некрасивая конструкция решила мою проблему:

```
     item['city'] = item['city'].encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
```